# Obtain "rank" using Doctrine 2 ORM and OneToOne in Repository

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, doctrine, zend-framework3

I'm finding it almost impossible to achieve my desired result, after so many attempts with different solutions (sub query, raw query, etc) found here and on other websites, I must ask this question.

My goal is to extract/get each "projects" rank based on their "score".

Consider "score" as int and with values like 1,2,6,4,8,10,200, etc.

The rank would be like this:

Rank - Score

1. 200
2. 10
3. 8
4. 6

For my question to be as simple and clear as possible, I renamed my actual tables/entities as below:

**MainEntity** (main_table):

```
/**
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\Column(name="id")
* @ORM\GeneratedValue
*/
protected $id;

// other fields, un-related to this question

/**
* @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\SecondTable", mappedBy="second_table_data")
*/
protected $second_table;

/**
* @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\ThirdTable", mappedBy="third_table_data")
* 
*/
protected $third_table;
```

**SecondEntity** (second_table):

```
/**
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\Column(name="id")
* @ORM\GeneratedValue
*/
protected $id;

// other fields, un-related to this question

/**
* @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\SecondTable", inversedBy="second_table")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="project_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
private $second_table_data;
```

**ThirdEntity** (third_table):

```
/**
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\Column(name="id")
* @ORM\GeneratedValue
*/
protected $id;

// other fields, un-related to this question

/** 
 * @ORM\Column(name="score")  
 */
protected $score;

/**
* @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\ThirdTable", inversedBy="third_table")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="project_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
private $third_table_data;
```

And the repository function to select "all projects" ordered by their score:

```
public function findAllProjects()
{
    $entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();

    $queryBuilder = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();

    $queryBuilder->select('u')
       ->from(MainEntity::class, 'u')
       ->leftJoin('u.third_table', 't')
       ->orderBy('t.score', 'DESC');

    return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

This works fine (I believe) as I get all the "projects" from **main_table** + **second_table** + **third_table** based on their "project_id".

However the issue is that I cannot find a way to calculate or get each project's "rank" number correctly. I also tried to use a "foreach" and use the "index" as "rank" but that will not work properly because I am using *ORMPaginator* so each time you click a "page" that "foreach" "index" will reset from 0.

I hope the question is clear enough and gives you a clear understanding of my problem.

Please advise how can I achieve this, and if my whole approach for this is wrong please point it out.

Every advice/hint/solution is highly appreciated.

Comment: Basically, you want to do a left join and order by a field in the join table, is that correct?

What is missing in the return value of findAllProjects() that you would like to obtain?

Comment: @SergioRinaudo Simply ordering by a filed will not get me what I need/want, please look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/rank-function-in-mysql this is what I basically want. I can order them by "score" which is fine, but I want to get their "rank", 1,2,3,4 based on their score... does that make sense ?

Comment: Actually, you don't want "their rank", but their position in the ordered list.

Comment: It would be the same thing, so yes.

Comment: Have you tried add the [OrderBy Annotation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref_orderby) on the property you wish to order by, e.g. "score" ? (I mean, I see complicated attempts here, but you've also tagged Doctrine, so going for simplicity here -> next up [Criteria](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections) to filter a Collection of `MainEntity`)

Comment: Also, using the OrmPaginator, you should be able to get the position in array (current page, item 4 is the 5th item in array, so "key + 1") and the page with the page limit. So simply in foreach with `$key`: `$paginator->getPage() * $paginator->getLimit() + ((int) $key + 1)` (function names might be slightly off)

Comment: @rkeet I thought that solution too (calculate the item using paginator limit and current page), and I think it is still the best/easiest solution, but I didn't look for correct function names of `OrmPaginator`. It would be nice to post your solution, it could be the right one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, pay really attention on the column types.
All your columns are created by doctrine as `varchar(255)`, which isn't the ideal if those are number on which you'd want to make an `order by`. This is a snippet of the output of `vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:create --dump-sql`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE main_entity (
  id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

So, the first thing you must do is adding column types to your columns:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue
 */
protected $id;
```

I used this data:

```
third_table                      main_entity
+----+------------+-------+      +----+
| id | project_id | score |      | id |
+----+------------+-------+      +----+
| 1  | 1          | 8     |      | 1  |
| 2  | 2          | 10    |      | 2  |
| 3  | 3          | 6     |      | 3  |
| 4  | 4          | 200   |      | 4  |
+----+------------+-------+      +----+
```

Concerning the rank, which is substantially the row number, the SQL query is:

```sql
SELECT 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.score DESC) AS r_rank,
   t.score AS score 
FROM main_entity m 
LEFT JOIN third_table t ON m.id = t.project_id 
ORDER BY t.score DESC
-- LIMIT 2 OFFSET 2 -- Limits for pagination
without limits           with limits
+--------+-------+       +--------+-------+
| r_rank | score |       | r_rank | score |
+--------+-------+       +--------+-------+
| 1      | 200   |       | 3      | 8     |
| 2      | 10    |       | 4      | 6     |
| 3      | 8     |       +--------+-------+
| 4      | 6     |
+--------+-------+
```

Unluckily, `ROW_NUMBER` is not implemented for SQL queries. If you try this:

```php
$queryBuilder->select(['ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.score DESC)','t.score'])
        ->from(MainEntity::class, 'u')
        ->leftJoin('u.third_table', 't')
        ->orderBy('t.score', 'DESC');
$queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
```

You'll get the following error: `[Syntax Error] line 0, col 7: Error: Expected known function, got 'ROW_NUMBER'`
An alternative could be:

```php
$sql = 'SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.score DESC) AS r_rank,
            t.score AS score 
        FROM main_entity m 
        LEFT JOIN third_table t ON m.id = t.project_id 
        ORDER BY t.score DESC';
$results = $this->entityManager->getConnection()->executeQuery($sql);
```

I see that there is something similar in the paginator walkers (?!), but they are not supported for all databases, [as you can see in the walker itself](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/d528f7056886fa2ea114b3179946cc6a5e8d08ee/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Pagination/LimitSubqueryOutputWalker.php#L163):

```php
public function walkSelectStatement(SelectStatement $AST)
{
    if ($this->platformSupportsRowNumber()) {
        return $this->walkSelectStatementWithRowNumber($AST);
    }
    return $this->walkSelectStatementWithoutRowNumber($AST);
}

private function platformSupportsRowNumber()
{
    return $this->platform instanceof PostgreSqlPlatform
        || $this->platform instanceof SQLServerPlatform
        || $this->platform instanceof OraclePlatform
        || $this->platform instanceof SQLAnywherePlatform
        || $this->platform instanceof DB2Platform
        || (method_exists($this->platform, 'supportsRowNumberFunction')
            && $this->platform->supportsRowNumberFunction());
}
```

As last chance, you could 'add' indexes by yourself, even with the paginator.

If you know the page size and the current page, you can calculate the rank:

```php
$pageSize = 2;
$currentPage = 1;
$queryBuilder = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
$queryBuilder->select('t.score') // Here I use only the t.score, but you could put the whole class
        ->from(MainEntity::class, 'u')
        ->leftJoin('u.third_table', 't')
        ->orderBy('t.score', 'DESC');
$queryBuilder->setMaxResults($pageSize);
$queryBuilder->setFirstResult(($currentPage - 1) * $pageSize);

$paginator = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator($queryBuilder->getQuery());
$adapter = new \DoctrineORMModule\Paginator\Adapter\DoctrinePaginator($paginator);

$results = [];
$currentItem = 1 + ($currentPage - 1) * $pageSize;
foreach($adapter->getPaginator()->getIterator()->getArrayCopy() as $result){
    $results[] = [
        'rank' => $currentItem++,
        'item' => $result
    ];
}
var_dump($results);
```

Result:

```
$pageSize = 2;                                        $pageSize = 2;
$currentPage = 1;                                     $currentPage = 2;

Array                                                 Array
(                                                     (
    [0] => Array                                          [0] => Array
        (                                                     (
            [rank] => 1                                           [rank] => 3
            [item] => Array                                       [item] => Array
                (                                                     (
                    [score] => 200                                        [score] => 8
                )                                                     )

        )                                                     )

    [1] => Array                                          [1] => Array
        (                                                     (
            [rank] => 2                                           [rank] => 4
            [item] => Array                                       [item] => Array
                (                                                     (
                    [score] => 10                                         [score] => 6
                )                                                     )

        )                                                     )

)                                                     )
```